# Matplotlib Scatter plot with numpy row index as marker

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a numpy array and i'm trying to plot it with a scatter plot using matplotlib.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pylab as pl

pl.plot(matrix[:,0],matrix[:,1], 'ro')
```

This gives me something like : 
[image: plot]

Now i want to replace the red dots by a number correspondig to the index of the row in the numpy array. How could i do it ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this using `plt.text`:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import numpy as np
N = 100
matrix = np.random.rand(N,2)

plt.plot(matrix[:,0],matrix[:,1], 'ro', alpha = 0.5)
for i in range(matrix.shape[0]):
    plt.text(matrix[i,0], matrix[i,1], str(i))

plt.show()
```

[image]

If you want to **replace** the red dots, then set `alpha = 0.0`:

[image]

Comment: Oh I didn't think about that ! Thank you very much